# snapshot is null flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I try to show the results from JSON in a ListView in Flutter with a FutureBuilder. when i  inspect data like this  inspect(snapshot.data); i got this result

[image]

but when i inspect data like this inspect(snapshot.data['name]); i didn't receive any result.

i want to fetch data from api and display it in listview

any help please ?

My code :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    getproduct(widget.idproduct);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<dynamic> getproduct(int id) async {
    var response = await Network().getData('/publication/show/$id');
   
    var data = json.decode(response.body)['publication'];
    return data;
  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
     
      appBar: AppBar(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.grey[800],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 1, right: 16),
        child: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getproduct(widget.idproduct),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                inspect(snapshot.data);
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                    String price = snapshot.data[index]['price'];
                    String size = snapshot.data[index]['size'];
                    int id = int.parse('${snapshot.data[index]['user_id']}');
                  
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "$size",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your getProduct is an async method, there is a period of time (short or long) where the value is null. In your futurebuilder, try adding an if/else checking for snapshot.hasData, like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: getproduct(widget.idproduct),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            inspect(snapshot.data);
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(...)
            }
            // display something when there is no data in snapshot
          }
        )
```

Comment: when i inspect (snapshot.data['name']); i didn't receive any data . but inspect(snapshot.data) work fine. can you help me ?

Comment: You need to give us more information like the error from console.

Comment: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<dynamic>

Comment: Can you provide your json

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your json returns an array? try to print `snapshot.data[0]['name]` instead

Comment: print (snapshot.data[0]['name]); ==> it returns us the name correctly. how i can resolve that ?

Comment: The reason you can't inspect `snapshot.data['name]` is because `snapshot.data` is an array, so it first expects an index. Thus the error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' The relevant error-causing widget was FutureBuilder<dynamic>"

Comment: i tried to resolve it but i cannot do that .